# When does DOMError happen?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, cookies, local-storage, localforage

I am having problems trying to catch this error. I have a Backbone Marionette application, that works with browserify / gulp and Ecma5.

We are also using localforage that actually saves some information in localstorage / cookies / indexdb for some persistence client side.

After doing several tests in many computers, **and in some computer we get a DOMError with the following message leaving a blank page**:

```
message: "The requested version (1) is less than the existing version (2)."
(anonymous function)
@
app.js?0.1:1
(anonymous function)
@
vendors.js?0.1:16229
flush
@
vendors.js?0.1:16513
drainQueue
@
vendors.js?0.1:14819
DOMError
```

Where vendors is the bundle of all the libraries externals localforage / backbone marionette / jquery etc... and app is our bundle.

Hint: I believe this error comes when using localforage and indexdb, after removing cookies and removing local storage we don't get again this error.

Comment: After reading this document: http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#sec-domerror I see domerror happens for indexdb